# Is there an equivalent of the Harvard sentences for Russian?

Tags: фонетика

The Harvard sentences ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_sentences), [full list of sentences](https://www.cs.columbia.edu/%7Ehgs/audio/harvard.html)) are a set of English sentences that:

1. Are phonetically balanced in the sense that the phonemes that are used in the sentences appear at the same frequency they do in English.
2. Contain all phonemes that appear in English.

Here are a few examples of them:

1. Oak is strong and also gives shade.
2. Cats and dogs each hate the other.
3. The pipe began to rust while new.
4. Open the crate but don't break the glass.

**Question:** Is there an equivalent of the Harvard sentences for Russian, i.e. a phonetically balanced collection of Russian sentences containing all phonemes used in Russian?

Comment: (I think it's probably a good idea to mention (disclose?) that I've asked similar questions to this one for other languages ([Portuguese](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/9768), [Japanese](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/100345)). The present question isn't meant as spam or anything; my reason to ask it is that I recently started learning Russian and am looking for such a list of sentences to practice pronunciation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are listed in [*ГОСТ Р 50840-95 Передача речи по трактам связи*](https://files.stroyinf.ru/Data/95/9523.pdf):

> Г.1.1 Если хочешь быть **здоров**, советует Татьяна Илье / , чисть **зубы** пастой «Жемчуг»!
>
> Г.1.2 Вчера на московском заводе малолитражных **автомобилей** / состоялось собрание **молодежи и комсомольцев**
>
> Г.1.3 В клумбах сочинской здравницы **«Пуща»**, сообщает нам автоинспектор / , обожгли **шихту**
>
> Г.1.4 Тропический какаду — это **крупный** попугай? / Ты нe **злословишь**?
>
> Г.1.5 Актеры и актрисы драматического **театра** / часто покупают в этой аптеке **антибиотики**
>
> Г.1.6 **Нам** с вами сидеть и обсуждать эти слухи / **некогда**!
>
> Г.1.7 Так ты считаешь, что техникой мы обеспечены на **весь** сезон?

and a whole lot more of them.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is perfect!